# timeout for ngShow not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I am struggling on how to make the ngShow to determine the expression in a specified timeout period, it turns out that Angular can evaluate the expression but unable to reflect the changes in the view, here is the code I used

(View)

```
<button 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-primary rule-fade" 
    tooltip="{{ proLang.tooltip.ruleApplyBtnTxt }}" 
    ng-click="applyRule('basic')"
    ng-show="showApplyBtns(selectedRules, selectedObj)"
>

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span>
    Apply Rules
</button>
```

(Controller)
And the controller implementing the showApplyBtn function

```
//determine whether apply buttons should be shown
$scope.showApplyBtns = function(selectedRules, selectedObj) {
    $timeout(function() {
        return selectedRules.length == 1 && selectedObj.length == 1;
    },500);
};
```

Angular can determine the result (true or false), but it seems that the view doesn't reflect the changes.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than have `showApplyBtns` return a value, try assigning a value to a scope'ed variable.

Then your `button` can bind that value to `ng-show`

```
<button 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-primary rule-fade" 
    tooltip="{{ proLang.tooltip.ruleApplyBtnTxt }}" 
    ng-click="applyRule('basic')"
    ng-show="showApplyBtns"
>
```

Then change your controller so that `applyRule()` calls `updateShowAppyBtns` which will update the bound variable `showApplyBtns`

```
$scope.applyRule(...) {
    ...
    $scope.updateShowApplyBtns();
}

//determine whether apply buttons should be shown
$scope.updateShowApplyBtns = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.showApplyBtns = $scope.selectedRules.length == 1 && $scope.selectedObj.length == 1;
    },500);
};
```

Now when `updateShowApplyBtns` is called the `$timeout` function will update `$scope.showApplyBtns` and since that updated value is now bound to the `ng-show` on your button, your button's visibility will be updated.

EXPLANATION

The problem you were having is your `showApplyBtns` didn't actually return a value

```
$scope.showApplyBtns = function(selectedRules, selectedObj){
    $timeout(function(){
        return selectedRules.length == 1 && selectedObj.length == 1;
    },500);
    // return undefined (this is what actually happens here)
};
```

The anonymous function passed to `$timeout` returns a value...but this value is swallowed inside the `$timeout` function and `showApplyBtns` is left without anything to return, and so it returns the default value of `undefined`.

As you can imagine, it would not be appropriate for `showApplyBtns` to wait for `$timeout` to finish before returning its own value as that would block i/o (it would halt all executions while waiting, which is, by design, hard to do in javascript).

Since `showApplyBtns` can't wait for `$timeout` to return a value before returning its own value, there is little left to do other than utilize the persistence of state to manage the update (as illustrated in my answer above).

Hopefully that helps.  :)

Comment: Appreciate for the help, it works now, thanks! but I wonder why my approach does not work as it basically follows the same norm, my purpose is to delay the evaluation of my expression, the output is finally a boolean value, why my approach is not applicable?

Comment: Hey @user2499325 - I just updated my answer with an explanation as to why your previous code was not working as expected.

Comment: My appreciation for the clarification, I think my concept is clearer now upon reading the explanation, thank you very much! My respect!